# nested functions calling with multiple args in python

Tags: python, nested-function

This was the program for our test and I couldn't understand what is going on. This problem is called `nested function problem`.

```
def foo(a):
    def bar(b):
        def foobar(c):
            return a + b + c

        return foobar

    return bar


a, b, c = map(int,input().split())

res = foo(a)(b)(c)
print(res)
```

I have tried to debug this program but couldn't get any idea about why it is working.

Why is `foo(a)(b)(c)` not giving an error?

Why it is working and what it is called?

Comment: You should break the problem down into smaller parts. For example, what would `f` be if you write: `f = foo(a)`?

Comment: frist check `type( foo(a) )` - you get function `bar` and you can add `(...)` to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [closures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-closures/) concept, Inner functions are able to access variables of the enclosing scope.

If we do not access any variables from the enclosing scope, they are just ordinary functions with a different scope

```py
def get_add(x):
    def add(y):
        return x + y
    return add

add_function = get_add(10)
print(add_function(5))  # result is 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Python is an object, and functions as well, so you can pass them as arguments, return them, for example:

```
def inc(var):
    return var + 1


def my_func():
    return inc


my_inc = my_func()
print(my_inc) # <function inc at ...>
print(my_inc(1)) # 2
```

Moreover it's closed to decorator's concept:

```
def log_this(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('start', str(args))
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return res

    return wrapper


@log_this
def inc(var):
    return var + 1


print(inc(10))
```